# ¿Cómo hacer que un desplegable tome el valor seleccionado en html?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, dropdown

He creado un desplegable con una lista variable que se le pasa al html desde flask. El funcionamiento es correcto, cuando elijo un valor en el desplegable se ejecuta la función submit_form_p1_exercise() y desencadena una serie de funciones con el valor correcto. Sin embargo el valor que aparece en el desplegable sigue siendo el valor establecido por defecto "Seleccione una opcion". ¿Hay alguna razón por la cuál ocurra esto?

```html
<h4 style="font-family:Santander Text" >Choose a year</h4>
                <form name="years_p1_form" method="POST" action="/response_p1_year">
                    <div class="col" align="center">
                        <select name="p1_year" id="p1_years_box" onchange="submit_form_p1_year()" > 
                            <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </body>
</html>
<script>
function submit_form_p1_year()
{
    document.years_p1_form.submit();
}

<!-- Se crea la lista de paises disponibles para el ejercicio y año seleccionado-->
    {% if p1_year_chosen %}
        {% for country in countries %}
            node_p1_CountriesBox.innerHTML +='<option value="{{country}}"> {{country}} </option>'       
        {% endfor %}
        
</script>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y pegar el código en modo texto?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias. Ya lo he subido como texto.

Comment: A simple vista parece que al hacer submit estás navegando al action de tu formulario, y en el backend te vuelve a redirigir a la página del dropdown. Si se ha producido esa redirección, es normal que te vuelva a poner como seleccionado la primera opción. ¿Podrías confirmar que esto es así? Si es así tendrías que ver la forma de devolver en el backend la opción que acabas de recibir para que al recargar la página con el dropdwon se pueda seleccionar el último valor que has elegido.